# conditionally show/hide the icon in angular

Tags: angular

Hi,

The below code shows the bootstrap bell notification icon and a red circle in the template.

```
<a href dropdownToggle (click)="false">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell notification-icon">
         {{cookieData.search_unread_count}}
        </i>
</a>
```

[image]

This code {{cookieData.search_unread_count}} will get the count from the component and add the count to the bell icon's above red circular icon. Here the challenge is i want to hide the icon based on if the count is 0 then i want to hide the red circle above the bell and if count is greater than 0 then i have to show the red circle above the bell icon.

So conditionally how to add this?

Comment: a simple `*ngIf` is enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this :

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell" [ngClass]="cookieData.search_unread_count != 0 ? 'notification-icon': ' '"></i>
```

Updated Answer :

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell" [ngClass]="cookieData.search_unread_count != 0 ? 'notification-icon': ' '">
    <span *ngIf="cookieData.search_unread_count != 0">
        {{cookieData.search_unread_count}}
    </span>
</i>
```

Comment: Chandru, Thank you for this code. But there is a small issue in it. It hides the red circle but the count still comes like when the count is 0 then the 0 is showing. I want to hide that count also. When i apply the *ngIf then entire thing is getting hidden. Any inputs from your end.

Comment: @youi i updated answer can try like this it will be working

Comment: Chandru, i tried this but this *ngIf hiding the entire bell along with the count also. If count is 0 then it works fine but if count becomes > 0 then the bell is getting hidden.

Comment: Sorry Chandru, there was small mistake i made in the code. This logic works like a charm. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `*ngIf`, please see below

```
<a href dropdownToggle (click)="false" *ngIf="cookieData.search_unread_count > 0">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell notification-icon">
        {{cookieData.search_unread_count}}
    </i>
</a>
```

This will only display the icon when the count is greater than 0.

It is better to use `*ngIf` apposed to `[hidden]` as `*ngIf` actually removes the html and does not just add a `display: none;` to the element.